# Check whether json attribute is a list or an object in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonparser

I want to convert JSON returned from a service into a java object class. However, I get two types in the same JSON attribute and with that I get the following error `Expected begin array but it was begin object`. How to test before parsing JSON for my java class? Example of a JSON below:

```json
{
  "name": "ROMEU",
  "age": "24",
  "phone": "xx xxxx xxxx",
  "family": [
    {
      "kinship": "brother",
      "age": "20"
    },
    {
      "kinship": "sister",
      "age": "25"
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "name": "ROMEU",
  "age": "24",
  "phone": "xx xxxx xxxx",
  "family": {
    "kinship": "mother",
    "age": "20"
  }
}
```

Comment: You’re using Gson? Can you switch to Jackson?

Comment: In fact, please edit your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using Jackson, you can use [ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
```

If using GSON, something like

```
JSONObject response=new JSONObject(res);
if(res.get("family") instanceOf JSONObject) {
    // code for JSONObject
} else if(res.get("family") instanceOf JSONArray) {
    // code for JSONOArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to fix this is to change the service that returns such a JSON. It makes no sense to either return a `List` or a single object for the attribute `family`. This is complexifying what should be simple.
Why not returning always a `List`, that may happen to include a single object?

If this is not possible, then you will need all sorts of Jackson deserialization features to make this work. And why? Simply because the service that you are consuming is badly designed.

Comment: I agree, but I can't change the service. I've already explained and requested the change but nothing happens

Comment: I feared that. @dave's answer should do the trick in that case.